# RedLaserSDK.java from MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to use RedLaserSDK.java from MonoDroid.

- I've included redlasersdk.jar as AndroidJavaLibrary
- I've included RedLaserSDK.java as AndroidJavaSource
- I've included layout/video_view.axml
- I've included drawable/overlay_logo.png
- I've included raw/beep.ogg

My MainActivity looks something like this:

```cs
[Activity (Label = "MainActivity", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : TabActivity
{
  protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
  {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    TabHost tabHost = TabHost;

    // Tab for Scan
    TabHost.TabSpec scanspec = tabHost.NewTabSpec("Scan");
    scanspec.SetIndicator("", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.icon_scan_tab));
    Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, Java.Lang.Class.ForName("com.ebay.rlsample.RedLaserSDK"));
    scanspec.SetContent(scanIntent);

    tabHost.AddTab(scanspec); // Exception occurs here....
  }
}
```

But I get an ActivityNotFound exception:  Unable to explicitly find class 'MyApp/MyApp.com.ebay.rlsample.RedLaserSDK'

Any thoughts on what I might have wrong?

Comment: Alternatively, does anyone know how to get the right package and class name for a Java Source activity?  Even if I need to crack open the apt file to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I was missing was:

```
<activity android:name="com.ebay.rlsample.RedLaserSDK" android:label="RedLaserSDK"/>
```

Comment: Following your footsteps, I created a [TestApplication](https://github.com/pcoder/RedLaserDroid) for the latest RedLaserSDK (3.0.3). Thanks so very much.